# Modal NSWindow Notification after becoming visible again

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, visibility, nswindow

I am on objectiveC, OSX, not iOS. XCode 8.3

I have a preferences Window (custom NSWindow) that opens as a modal on my main window.

The preferences window itself contains a view with tabs. The tab height changes the windows size whenever one is clicked.

First Tab clicked:

[image]

Second Tab clicked:

[image]

Now if someone hides the application in the dock and activates it again, the preferences window becomes active with the height of tab 1, even if tab 2 is still active. So the content gets cut off.

[image]

What i need is some kind of notification that gets triggered on becoming active/visible again to trigger a resize of the window before it gets displayed.

I tried it with these notifications in my NSWindow subclass (with NSWindow delegate set).

```
- (void)windowDidResignMain:(NSNotification*)notification{
NSLog(@"windowDidResignMain");
}

- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification*)notification{
NSLog(@"windowDidResignKey");
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow{
    return YES;
}
```

But none of them worked. Is it because it's a modal window? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. What ways of placing/resizing are you using here? Auto Layout? Springs and struts?How are you resizing the windows? How are you populating/switching the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. My mistake - my tabViewController triggered a resize on viewWillAppear with always the first tab. I changed that to the current selected tab and that was it.